# Google App Script Add-Ons createAddonMenu() create a Help menu. How to call it?

Tags: google-apps-script

With the new Google App Script (new spreadsheet) when I create a menu for my Add-Ons using `createAddonMenu()` you will notice that Google add automatically a separator and a Help menu at the end. But I found nowhere documentation that tells what is the name of the function associated with the Help.

Would anybody know?

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
  .addItem('Test A', 'insertChart')
  .addItem('Test B', 'updateCharts')
  .addItem('Test C', 'updateCharts')
  .addToUi();
}
```

[image: Help Menu]

Comment: After further investigations the only reference I found of Add-Ons Help is during the publishing process: "In the Deploy as Add-on dialog that appears, enter your add-on's name, description, URL for a help page, and post-install tip.". It would seems the Help menu is populated from an URL provided during the publishing process.

Comment: VanacK is right. This option isn't available.

Comment: explained here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style

Answer (score 5):

I'm tired of seeing this question as unanswered!

The publishing process asks for a URL to which `Help` will point. You also get an opportunity to set things like a description whilst providing screen shots, promotional tiles and an icon.